# Keeping track of all history of audio player (previous, next buttons and random selection from browser)

Tags: javascript, audio-player

I need to keep track of all history of which songs have been played with audio player. The difficult part is when user continuously clicks on next and previous button.

Testing data (songs):

```
export const tracksData = [
  {
    name: 'song-1',
    path: 'path.mp3',
    id: 'song-1-id',
  }, {
    name: 'song-2',
    path: 'path.mp3',
    id: 'song-2-id',
  }, {
    name: 'song-3',
    path: 'path.mp3',
    id: 'song-3-id',
  }, {
    name: 'song-4',
    path: 'path.mp3',
    id: 'song-4-id',
  }, {
    name: 'song-5',
    path: 'path.mp3',
    id: 'song-5-id',
  }, {
    name: 'song-6',
    path: 'path.mp3',
    id: 'song-6-id',
  }, {
    name: 'song-7',
    path: 'path.mp3',
    id: 'song-7-id',
  }, {
    name: 'song-8',
    path: 'path.mp3',
    id: 'song-8-id',
  }, {
    name: 'song-9',
    path: 'path.mp3',
    id: 'song-9-id',
  }, {
    name: 'song-10',
    path: 'path.mp3',
    id: 'song-10-id',
  }
];
```

Some variables used and their usage behind them:

```
// currentPlayingTrackIndex = index of tracks array 
// trackQueIndex = position of playedTrackedIndexes
// trackStartPoint === 0 then at the the start of the que and should take just next indexes
```

Initialize tracks (working as intended):

```
const initializeTracks = (tracks) => {
  const { path, name, id } = tracks[0];

  const playingTrack = {
    path,
    name,
    id,
  };

  return {
    playingTrack,
    currentPlayingTrackIndex: 0,
    trackQueIndex: 0,
    trackStartPoint: 0,
    playedTrackIndexes: [0]
  }
};
```

Get next track (when next button is clicked or track ends):

```
const getNextTrack = (tracks, tracksQueData) => {
  const { currentPlayingTrackIndex, trackQueIndex, trackStartPoint, playedTrackIndexes } = tracksQueData;
  const isCurrentTrackTheLastOfPlayQue = trackStartPoint === 0;

  const nextTrackIndex = isCurrentTrackTheLastOfPlayQue ? currentPlayingTrackIndex + 1 : playedTrackIndexes[trackQueIndex + 1];

  const { path, name, id } = tracks[nextTrackIndex];

  const nextTrack = {
    path,
    name,
    id,
  };

  const nextTrackQueIndex = trackQueIndex + 1;
  const startPoint = trackStartPoint === 0 ? trackStartPoint : trackStartPoint - 1;

  return {
    playingTrack: nextTrack,
    currentPlayingTrackIndex: nextTrackIndex,
    trackQueIndex: nextTrackQueIndex,
    trackStartPoint: startPoint,
    playedTrackIndexes: [...playedTrackIndexes, nextTrackIndex]
  }  
};
```

Get previous track (when previous button is clicked on):

```
const getPreviousTrack = (tracks, tracksQueData) => {
  const { currentPlayingTrackIndex, trackQueIndex, trackStartPoint, playedTrackIndexes } = tracksQueData;
  
  const previousTrackQueIndex = trackQueIndex - 1;
  const previousTrackIndex = playedTrackIndexes[previousTrackQueIndex];
  const { path, name, id } = tracks[previousTrackIndex];

  const previousTrack = {
    path,
    name,
    id,
  };

  const startPoint = trackStartPoint + 1;

  return {
    playingTrack: previousTrack,
    currentPlayingTrackIndex: previousTrackIndex,
    trackQueIndex: previousTrackQueIndex,
    trackStartPoint: startPoint,
    playedTrackIndexes: [...playedTrackIndexes, previousTrackIndex]
  }
};
```

Failing test case for getPreviousTrack. Obviously it doesn't work with use case like this anymore. I think the whole logic needs to be rewritten to keep track of the history correctly, but I am not sure how exactly. Maybe using uuid for each played track, but how does that help me exactly? I am actually baffled how complex can a simple audio player logic be (if you really want to keep track of the whole play history correctly and not just reset it at some point for a simplified logic).

```
it('Should return correct track object when getting previous track and the same tracks have been played multiple times, more complex', () => {
  const tracksQueData = {
    currentPlayingTrackIndex: 5,
    trackQueIndex: 5,
    trackStartPoint: 0,
    playedTrackIndexes: [0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  };

  const track = getPreviousTrack(tracksTestData, tracksQueData);

  expect(track).toEqual(
    {
      playingTrack: {
        name: 'song-4',
        path: 'path.mp3',
        id: 'song-4-id',
      },
    currentPlayingTrackIndex: 4,
    trackQueIndex: 4,
    trackStartPoint: 1,
    playedTrackIndexes: [0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4]
  })
});
```

There is also an option to select tracks from the library as well. This is an separate function, which I have not yet implemented. So lets say user plays indexes [0, 1, 2], then selects tracksData[7] then the playedTrackIndexes would be [0, 1, 2, 7].

Working more simple test case:

```
it('Should return correct track object when getting previous track and the same tracks have been played multiple times', () => {
  const tracksQueData = {
    currentPlayingTrackIndex: 4,
    trackQueIndex: 4,
    trackStartPoint: 4,
    playedTrackIndexes: [0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4]
  };

  const track = getPreviousTrack(tracksTestData, tracksQueData);

  expect(track).toEqual(
    {
      playingTrack: {
        name: 'song-4',
        path: 'path.mp3',
        id: 'song-4-id',
      },
    currentPlayingTrackIndex: 3,
    trackQueIndex: 3,
    trackStartPoint: 5,
    playedTrackIndexes: [0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3],
  })
});
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction how to implement it better? Obviously this logic only works if user doesn't click on previous/next buttons continuously. Seriously stuck here.

Comment: Do you want the user to select previous and play the previous song they listened to, or the previous song in the trackData(playlist) the way it was sorted. And what about next?

Comment: Like I said keep track of all the history. When user clicks on next it should either take next index from tracksData (playlist) OR if the user isn't exhausted the history que (meaning user has clicked on previous buttons) then it should take those songs first. So lets say user plays tracksData[0], tracksData[1], tracksData[2] then, selects previous so it should be tracksData[1] and then next again then it should be tracksData[2]. See my test case, which is failing for an example. But basically: no history then next -> next index, prev -> prev index, history -> exhaust que before

Comment: The difficult part is that I want to keep track of all songs played. I can't explain it any more simple then all history: it should play back in order it was played before.

Comment: This example [0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. In case like this I would want it to play index 4, 3, 3, 2, 1 when clicked on previous. And 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 when clicked next. User might not just click next there though. User might click like this as well: click next 2 times, then maybe 3 times previous.

Comment: For this use case I would say it is a great idea to use a class for the player

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (very subtle) issue I see here is confusion of the meanings of `currentPlayingTrackIndex` and `trackQueIndex`.

`currentPlayingTrackIndex` is a bit like the ID of the playing track - it is the index of the playing track inside the `tracksData` array.

Meanwhile `trackQueIndex` is the index of the playing track within the history array. They won't always be the same as each other, which you've "expected" in your test function.

**So actually, your code and logic is correct, but the usage of these variables in your testing function is wrong.**

In your test function you should define the `tracksQueData` differently, so that the `trackQueIndex` points to the element stored inside of `currentPlayingTrackIndex` within the `playedTrackIndexes` array, and use `trackQueIndex` to keep track of where in the history you are.

I.e., `currentPlayingTrackIndex` should always be given by `tracksQueData.playedTrackIndexes[tracksQueData.trackQueIndex]`.

However you have defined both as `5` when the history array is actually longer. In your non-working example, the queue index variable should be 21, not 5.

To know when to start playing new tracks, you cleverly use the `trackStartPoint` variable and there is no logic error here.

Here is proof that this code works if you give it valid test data for it to parse:

```js
var tracksData = [
  {
    name: 'song-1',
    path: 'path.mp3',
    id: 'song-1-id',
  }, {
    name: 'song-2',
    path: 'path.mp3',
    id: 'song-2-id',
  }, {
    name: 'song-3',
    path: 'path.mp3',
    id: 'song-3-id',
  }, {
    name: 'song-4',
    path: 'path.mp3',
    id: 'song-4-id',
  }, {
    name: 'song-5',
    path: 'path.mp3',
    id: 'song-5-id',
  }, {
    name: 'song-6',
    path: 'path.mp3',
    id: 'song-6-id',
  }, {
    name: 'song-7',
    path: 'path.mp3',
    id: 'song-7-id',
  }, {
    name: 'song-8',
    path: 'path.mp3',
    id: 'song-8-id',
  }, {
    name: 'song-9',
    path: 'path.mp3',
    id: 'song-9-id',
  }, {
    name: 'song-10',
    path: 'path.mp3',
    id: 'song-10-id',
  }
];

function initializeTracks (tracks) {
  const { path, name, id } = tracks[0];

  const playingTrack = {
    path,
    name,
    id,
  };

  return {
    playingTrack,
    currentPlayingTrackIndex: 0,
    trackQueIndex: 0,
    trackStartPoint: 0,
    playedTrackIndexes: [0]
  }
}

function getNextTrack (tracks, tracksQueData) {
  const { currentPlayingTrackIndex, trackQueIndex, trackStartPoint, playedTrackIndexes } = tracksQueData;
  const isCurrentTrackTheLastOfPlayQue = trackStartPoint === 0;

  const nextTrackIndex = isCurrentTrackTheLastOfPlayQue ? currentPlayingTrackIndex + 1 : playedTrackIndexes[trackQueIndex + 1];

  const { path, name, id } = tracks[nextTrackIndex];

  const nextTrack = {
    path,
    name,
    id,
  };

  const nextTrackQueIndex = trackQueIndex + 1;
  const startPoint = trackStartPoint === 0 ? trackStartPoint : trackStartPoint - 1;

  return {
    playingTrack: nextTrack,
    currentPlayingTrackIndex: nextTrackIndex,
    trackQueIndex: nextTrackQueIndex,
    trackStartPoint: startPoint,
    playedTrackIndexes: [...playedTrackIndexes, nextTrackIndex]
  }  
}


function getPreviousTrack (tracks, tracksQueData) {
  const { currentPlayingTrackIndex, trackQueIndex, trackStartPoint, playedTrackIndexes } = tracksQueData;
  
  const previousTrackQueIndex = trackQueIndex - 1;
  const previousTrackIndex = playedTrackIndexes[previousTrackQueIndex];
  const { path, name, id } = tracks[previousTrackIndex];

  const previousTrack = {
    path,
    name,
    id,
  };

  const startPoint = trackStartPoint + 1;

  return {
    playingTrack: previousTrack,
    currentPlayingTrackIndex: previousTrackIndex,
    trackQueIndex: previousTrackQueIndex,
    trackStartPoint: startPoint,
    playedTrackIndexes: [...playedTrackIndexes, previousTrackIndex]
  }
}





function test() {
  const tracksQueData = {
    currentPlayingTrackIndex: 5, // like id
    trackQueIndex: 21, // index in history
    trackStartPoint: 0,
    playedTrackIndexes: [0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  };
  
  console.log("Currently playing", tracksQueData.currentPlayingTrackIndex);
  let prev = getPreviousTrack(tracksData, tracksQueData);
  console.log("Prev track:", prev.currentPlayingTrackIndex);
  
  prev = getPreviousTrack(tracksData, prev);
  console.log("Prev again:", prev.currentPlayingTrackIndex);
  // ... so on
  
  console.log("History:", ...prev.playedTrackIndexes);
  
  console.log("Now, play next few tracks");
  let next = getNextTrack(tracksData, prev);
  console.log("Prev again:", next.currentPlayingTrackIndex);
  
  next = getNextTrack(tracksData, next);
  console.log("Prev again:", next.currentPlayingTrackIndex);
  
  next = getNextTrack(tracksData, next);
  console.log("Prev again:", next.currentPlayingTrackIndex);
}

console.clear();
test();
```

```html
<h3>Please go full screen to be able to see all of the content written here</h3>
<ul>
  <li> Look at the history array in the `test()` function here.
  <li> To start with, it is playing track 5.
  <li> Call `getPrevTrack` once, and it plays track 4. 
  <li> Call it again and it plays track 3. 
  <li> Now look at the history array (in the console). You will see the tracks 4 and 3 appended to it after the initially playing one, 5.
  <br><br>
  <li> If you now call getNextTrack() it will play track 4 <br>
  <li> Call it again and you get track 5 <br>
  <li> Call it again, and it skips the ones that were <em>just</em> appended to the history array and instead plays the one that comes after 5 in the playlist array - in other words, track 6.
</ul>
```

To make it **very** clear, the issue is that

```js
const tracksQueData = {
    currentPlayingTrackIndex: 5,
    trackQueIndex: 5,
    trackStartPoint: 0,
    playedTrackIndexes: [0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
};
```

is wrong as this data cannot be created if you use the functions `getNextTrack` and `getPreviousTrack`.

Instead, it should be:

```js
const tracksQueData = {
    currentPlayingTrackIndex: 5, // like id
    trackQueIndex: 21, // index in history
    trackStartPoint: 0,
    playedTrackIndexes: [0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
};
```

The error is that, again, as I mentioned before, you are using `trackQueIndex` incorrectly. In your code example above, you assign `5` to it.

So it points to:

```
[0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, ...]
   _____________^
```

instead of to

```
..., 2, 3, 4, 5]
      ________^
```

for it to point to the correct track in the history array, it must be set to the value `21`. Because when the function `getPrevTrack` is called, it will decrement and point to `4`.

The reason why you thought your code didn't work is because when it had the wrong value of `5` assigned to it, when it decrements it becomes `4` and points to the track `0` instead of `4`, as `0` is at index 4 in the history array.

I hope that is clear.

Comment: I don't get it. You didn't change anything except for turn const into function. Also, doesn't work. There is no point in turning this into class as well. I want them it to be pure functions, which can be easily tested.

Comment: @MysteryMan right, I've copied and pasted the wrong code here, sorry, I'll update it once I get home. And as for testing, classes are isolated and encapsulated which makes them easy to test on their own. Of course, you know the context of your project better than me so in the end it's your decision.

Comment: Thank you, looking forward to seeing your code :).

Comment: @MysteryMan check my answer again, I hope it makes sense now. Please read all of the answer, even the parts you think you've already read because I updated a few parts of it

Comment: I see that you added explanation. Did you update code part as well? Looks like it is the same as before, at least when I put it in diffchecker.

Comment: @MysteryMan yes I updated the test function. If you want to check if it works, don't use your original testing function and testing data. The playlist array is ok, but the trackQueueData is logically impossible to exist the way you have defined it. I would say use multiple calls of the functions to construct it, don't take shortcuts unless you're sure you know what you're typing is correct. That is why you get the impression that the functions don't work

Comment: I get it perfectly that the original test cases don't work. I was asking if you updated my original functions at all - seems like you didn't. If I understand correctly you explained why trackQueIndex doesn't work and in test function you have set correct trackQueIndex  in which these functions would work. I will just have to figure out how keep the correct trackQueIndex and update my functions - correct?

Comment: @MysteryMan yes, exactly. And the original functions will return the correct value for trackQueIndex.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood, you have your set of data, which contains a playlist. You want to be able to keep a record of the playing history. You also want to be able to click on a song and play it, aswell using the next and previous buttons to navigate through the history if possible, otherwise you want to go through the playlist.
Use the browser's console to have a better view of the console logs.

To make it as simple as possible, I would do the following:

```js
const playlist = [{
    name: 'song-1',
    path: 'path.mp3',
    id: 'song-1-id',
}, {
    name: 'song-2',
    path: 'path.mp3',
    id: 'song-2-id',
}, {
    name: 'song-3',
    path: 'path.mp3',
    id: 'song-3-id',
}, {
    name: 'song-4',
    path: 'path.mp3',
    id: 'song-4-id',
}, {
    name: 'song-5',
    path: 'path.mp3',
    id: 'song-5-id',
}, {
    name: 'song-6',
    path: 'path.mp3',
    id: 'song-6-id',
}, {
    name: 'song-7',
    path: 'path.mp3',
    id: 'song-7-id',
}, {
    name: 'song-8',
    path: 'path.mp3',
    id: 'song-8-id',
}, {
    name: 'song-9',
    path: 'path.mp3',
    id: 'song-9-id',
}, {
    name: 'song-10',
    path: 'path.mp3',
    id: 'song-10-id',
}];

const history = [];
let historyIndex;
let currentSong = {};

function playSong(song, fromHistory = false) {
    // if a song is not played from the history, it shall be added to the history and historyIndex will be set as the latest song
    if (!fromHistory && song !== currentSong){
        history.push(song);
        historyIndex = history.length - 1;
    }
    currentSong = song;
    console.log("current: ", currentSong.name);
    console.log("playing from history: ", fromHistory);
    console.log("history: ", history);
    console.log("historyIndex: ", historyIndex);
}

// a general function for the NEXT button
function next() {
    if (currentSong === {}) return; // do nothing if no song is selected
    
    // checks whether there is a history or not
    if (history.length === 0) {
        nextInPlaylist();
    } else {
        nextInHistory();
    }
}

// plays next song in the playlist
function nextInPlaylist() {
    // finding the currentIndex of the selected song
    const currentIndex = playlist.findIndex(s => s.id === currentSong.id);
    
    // checks if it is the last song on the playlist. If yes, it should just start from the beginning again
    if (currentIndex === playlist.length - 1) {
        playSong(playlist.at(0));
    } else {
        playSong(playlist.at(currentIndex + 1));
    }
}

// plays next song in the history
function nextInHistory() {
    // checks if it is the last song on the history. If yes, it should just play the next song in the playlist
    if (historyIndex === history.length - 1) {
        nextInPlaylist();
    } else {
        historyIndex++;
        playSong(history.at(historyIndex), true);
    }
}

function back() {
    if (currentSong === {}) return; // do nothing if no song is selected
    
    // checks whether there is a history or not
    if (history.length === 0) {
        backInPlaylist();
    } else {
        backInHistory();
    }
}

// plays previous song in the playlist
function backInPlaylist() {
    const currentIndex = playlist.findIndex(s => s.id === currentSong.id);
    
    // checks if it is the first song on the playlist. If yes, it should just start from the end
    if (currentIndex === 0) {
        playSong(playlist.at(-1));
    } else {
        playSong(playlist.at(currentIndex - 1));
    }
}

// plays previous song in the history
function backInHistory() {
    // checks if it is the first song on the history. If yes, it should just play the previous song in the playlist
    if (historyIndex === 0) {
        backInPlaylist();
    } else {
        historyIndex--;
        playSong(history.at(historyIndex), true);
    }
}


function selectRandomSong() {
    const maxSongIndex = playlist.length - 1;
    const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxSongIndex);
    playSong(playlist.at(randomNum));
}
```

```html
<button onClick="selectRandomSong()">Select random</button><br>
<button onClick="next()">Next</button><br>
<button onClick="back()">Back</button>
```

The explanation of the code is also included in comments.

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't work as excepted. For example if you click random and then click back it doesn't get the correct order (doesn't always happen, but often). Also, this code you provided is very hard to test (since you aren't using pure functions) and needs work. For example, there is no need to use global variables like history, historyIndex, currentSong. These should be passed into function as one variable something like this: const tracksQueData = {
  history: [],
  historyIndex: 0,
  currentSong: {},
}; Same goes for songs. Thank you for trying though, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to offer my own option for saving the history of listened tracks. For now, the player only has the previous and next track buttons, but in the future I want to make another playlist in the form of a list. And so, after clicking the buttons, the index of the selected track is added to the end of the tracks array. Its contents are immediately displayed on the page. There are 2 main modes - recording a sequence of playing tracks and playing this sequence. These modes are switched by the corresponding buttons.

```html
<audio id=audio controls></audio><br /><br />
<button onclick="getTrack(-1)" title="previous"><<</button>
<button onclick="getTrack(1)" title="next">>></button><br /><br />
Action on a sequence:
<button onclick="action = 'Recording'; indexes = []; trackIndex = 0; act.innerText = 'is recorded'">Recording</button> 
<button onclick="action = 'playing'; act.innerText = 'is played'; current.innerText = indexes[0]; audio.src = folder + tracks[indexes[0]]; audio.play()" id=next>Playing</button>
<span id=act></span><br /><br />
Indexes: <span id=list></span><br /><br />
Current index: <span id=current></span>
<script>
const tracks = ["track1.mp3", "track2.mp3", "track3.mp3", "track4.mp3", "track5.mp3", "track6.mp3", "track7.mp3", "track8.mp3"];
let indexes = [];
let index = 0;
let trackIndex = 0;
let listIndex = 0;
let action = "recording";
let folder = "https://mysynthesizer.github.io/index.hetemeel/";
act.innerText = 'is recorded'
audio.src = folder + tracks[0];
function getTrack(direction){
    if(action == 'recording'){
        trackIndex += direction;
        if(trackIndex >= tracks.length) trackIndex = 0;
        if(trackIndex < 0) trackIndex = tracks.length - 1;
        index = trackIndex;
        indexes.push(index);
        list.innerText = indexes;       
    }
    if(action == 'playing'){
        listIndex += direction;
        if(listIndex >= indexes.length) listIndex = 0;
        if(listIndex < 0) listIndex = indexes.length - 1;
        index = indexes[listIndex];
        trackIndex = index;
    }
    current.innerText = index;
    audio.src = folder + tracks[index];
    if (direction) audio.play();
}
getTrack(0);
</script>
```

Comment: You should not submit code but help to improve/solve the existing code.